# React, display content of root node while loading

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have following template:

```
...
<body>
  <div id="root">Loading...</div>
</body>
...
```

and React component is something very obvious like

```
ReactDOM.render(RootContainer, document.getElementById('root'));
```

(Examples are simplified as much as possible)

What I want is to show contents of the div while React is processing request and to replace "Loading..." with actual app once it is loaded.

How should I do that? I see a way of adding another div with "loading" message and hiding it once app is loaded but it seems to me like a dirty way

Comment: Why does it seem dirty to you? I consider it perfectly valid way to indicate your app is loading.

Comment: Just a feeling that it could be better with the "loading state contents" inside the same div where the app will appear. I may be wrong as I'm newbie in frontend - that's why I'm here :)

Answer (score 1):

`ReactDOM.render` takes an optional third callback parameter as described in the [top level API documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.render), so you could do something like the following:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'), function() {
  document.getElementById('placeholder').style.display = 'none';
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I've meant in my suggestion, just wondering if there are another ways of doing it like "replace node contents only when React have everything ready"

Comment: @Chvanikoff what do you mean by ready? If you want to block rendering then maybe you should make sure you do image preloading / ajax requests inside `componentWillMount` or `componentWillUpdate`?

Comment: Initial state is loaded via websockets and all the app is just tons of streaming info - unless the initial state is loaded, there's almost a blank page with just couple links. So what I want is to display some of the info in the div - kind of very simplified server-side rendering